# Is ASP.NET written site is available for Android phones

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, crm

I need to write simple CRM which will be available as a website on Windows PCs and Android tablets.

**The question: Is the ASP .NET written website will be working on android phone?** I mean: textfields, buttons, lists? Will it work on Windows Phone?

I mean that below:

[image]

If not is there alternative?

Is this is alternative?:

[image]

Comment: You need to understand the difference between server technology and what HTML stands for and how it is sent over network. But for a short description I have given an answer for your help.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is an universal markup language. Once you render your html items with the server platform, it does not matter whether you used ASP.net, Django or PHP Zend, the generated output has to follow the universal rules and thus be viewed to any browser. If the browser cannot render it correctly then its that browsers shortcoming. I would suggest you read about HTML, server and client a few little articles before continuing. Will help you in long run.

The wiki page is a good place to start -

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML

So, in short unless you are using something that is not html, you should not worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, but...
I would suggest you consider using some other web technologies to make the user experience on touch based clients a little bit better. What looks good on desktops and mobile computers would usually not be easy to operate on phones and tablets, because the controls are not optimized for touch.
There are a number of web technologies (all based on javascript and css) that would help you creating responsive and touch friendly web site.
Try looking for:

- AngularJs - for full blown MVC web app (my favorite with Bootstrap, see below)
- jQuery and jQuery UI - in case your web is relatively simple.
- Bootstrap - this will help you with responsiveness and adjusting the screen for mobile devices.

There are other web technologies that can be as effective as these, and Microsoft is already integrating jQuery with web forms, AFAIK.

Hope this helps.